# What topics are related to "concept drift"?

Tags: terminology

The term "concept drift" specifically relates to a model changing over time.  However, a similar phenomenon may manifest in, e.g., spatial data, where a topographical model changes behavior at a land/water boundary.  Another example may be in modeling the properties of a chemical substance, which change in behavior across a phase-change.  In general, this sort of situation where a "global" model does not apply is ubiquitous, and I am trying to accumulate examples and related research.

What other terms and research relate to this global-model problem?

Comment: This sounds too broad/open-ended to me. Any community votes?  (I don't think the other examples you give are the same as topic shift.  What's fundamental about *time* specifically is that we can only train on items from the past, so concept list is a fundamental problem because it means we are forced to use the model on values that it wasn't trained on.  In contrast, with spatial shift, it is plausible that we could collect a training set that captures data from both sides of the land/water boundary: but we can't capture data from both sides of the past/future boundary.)

Comment: ... this casts concept drift in an "unsolvable" light.  There exist any number of methods for dealing with the problem of concept drift, and none of them involve knowing the future.  The general procedure is to look at past data, determine if data have recently been behaving differently than in the distant past, and to update the model accordingly.  Note that this procedure is entirely confined to past data.  The distinction between "recent" and "non-recent" is no different than the distinction between land and water.